How do I fix this garage bracket? It looks like it was held by glue?
I had my garage to manually open and locked it. After power came back I opened it with the opener and the top bracket broke. It looks to be fitted in a rivet at top and glue. Can I just put some screws and call it a day?


We need one or more additional pictures to see how the door is constructed. Some of these doors are held together by a comination of adhesive and heavy screws, connecting the skin to a frame of strong vertical and horizontal members. The adhesive connections are not supposed to be under local strain. All force paths are supposed to be steel screw, steel bolt or steel clamp secured by a steel screw. There is supposed to be a horizontal rib at the top of your door, but I don't see it. Need a pic from farther back.

Could be the top horizontal rib is inside the inward bend and all you would have to do is drill through and secure with garage door self tapping screws. The installer was perhaps supposed to secure that with self drilling screws. Better for a DIY job would be bolts with nuts. One or even two washers, one under the nut and maybe another under the head.

If a door like this is to be operated manually it would not need a strong horizontal rib at the top because the force to llft is applied lower down near the middle of the door. But if a standard top pull door opener is to be installed is could be that the installer was supposed to install an aditional horizontal rib at or near the top to distribute the ling force laterally.

I would use machine bolts/screws.
They use nuts and maybe washers like regular bolts, but screw diameters and heads.
The bracket should be thick enough, but the door would like a flat washer to spread out the force.
The holes in the door frame might need to be drilled out to the same size as the bracket holes.
You want the bolt to just slip though the holes.

Yeah, you could cut a flat piece of metal to fit the door channel (on the opposite side of the bracket) and drill holes in it for the machine screws, to spread the load.

@Huesmann   One way, but ready made flat washers are available also.
